# Is the entire history, we read, accurate?

Tags: ancient-history, historical-research, historical-accuracy

In today's era, having great advanced technologies, we get many rumors. So how can we write the historical facts so firmly.

We talk about ancient personalities, their quotes, their lives, etc. so firmly.

It is said that many ancient properties passed on **orally**.
How can vast oral things **like vedas** be so precise?

Comment: As 98.543521% of all scientific studies on the subject will tell you, "precise" does not mean "accurate".

Answer (score 2):

Things like the Vedas (or Genesis, Greek myths, American Indian creation stories, &c) aren't precise.  Sometimes they're retellings of actual events, distorted by being orally passed down through many generations, sometimes they're just made-up stories.

Sometimes we can correlate the stories with physical evidence.  If for instance a particular tradition mentions a king of Babylon named Ashurbanipal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashurbanipal and archeologists excavate the ruins of Babylon and find lots of clay tablets &c mentioning him, we can reasonably conclude that there indeed was such a king.  (But we'd conclude that from the tablets even if we didn't have the story...)